# why my table doesn't respond when click a row

Tags: javascript, jsp

I ceate a JSP which fetch value from database and displayed it in a table. Now I want to create a click function for the table. Click the row it will display some value. I use a js code for it but when I click the line nothing happened. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="SCOfetch.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>First Page</title>
<% JCOtest connection1 = new JCOtest(); %>
    <%
        ArrayList<CompanyRecord> list = new ArrayList<CompanyRecord>();
        list = connection1.step4QueryTable();
    %>
//*This is the click function*
<script language="javascript">

function showBgc(idn){
alert (idn);
}

</script>    
</head>
<body>
    <c:set var="greeting" value="Hello, World!"/>

<!--    <img id="image-1" alt="" src="img/snow.jpg" width="300" height="300"/> -->
//This is the result table 
<table>
    <%
    int size=list.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){  
        CompanyRecord news =(CompanyRecord)list.get(i);  
        %>
        <tr>
        <td onclick="showBgc(i)"><%=news.getValue("Code") %></td>
        <td onclick="showBgc(i)"><%=news.getValue("Name") %></td>
        </tr><%
    }               
    %>              
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And I debug it in IE. the html is like

```
 <tr>
     <td onclick="showBgc(i)">DE01</td>
     <td onclick="showBgc(i)">Country Template DE</td>
 </tr>
```

and the error is i not defined.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and produce a [mcve] WITHOUT any JSP. This is not a JSP issue!

Comment: Does it show alert() that shows nothing? Or there is no alert() at all?

Comment: no alert() at all

Comment: Have you checked the developer console of your browser? I suspect it will show an error in the lines of "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined".

Comment: Is your jsp code running without any errors ?

Comment: I debug in IE and from console the code is like <tr>
        <td onclick="showBgc(i)">CZ01</td>
        <td onclick="showBgc(i)">Country Template CZ</td>
        </tr>  and error is i undefined

Comment: @kkluo See Sohail's answer below for the solution and see [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) for more information. (That article is about PHP, but it applies to Java/JSP's as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to print the `i` value in the `showBgc` `function call`. Change `showBgc(i)` to `showBgc(<%=i%>)`, otherwise the function will take `i` as a string value.

**Example:**

```
%>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="showBgc(<%=i%>)"><%=news.getValue("Code") %></td>
        <td onclick="showBgc(<%=i%>)"><%=news.getValue("Name") %></td>
    </tr> 
<%
```

To show `code` and `Name`.

```
<tr>
  <td onclick="showBgc('<%=news.getValue("Code") %>')"><%=news.getValue("Code") %></td>
  <td onclick="showBgc('<%=news.getValue("Name") %>')"><%=news.getValue("Name") %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Still not working. I guess the issus is about the parameter i definition?

Comment: Now it worked.Thx.One more question if you don't mind. If I want to alert the value of Code and Name instead. What should I do?